# Conditional highlighting based on whether cells are empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to do conditional highlighting for a given row.

1. If a specific cell in a row *isn't blank*, then I want more highlighting to be done on the row;
2. If (1) is **true**, then I want each cell in that row which *isn't* blank to be filled with the same color.

One important factor is that I have functions which return no values, making the cell appear blank (e.g. `""`). These cells should be highlighted if (1) is **true**. Because of this I have been using the length function `LEN()` to determine if a cell is empty as `ISBLANK()` won't work.

The current highlighting rule I am using is:

`=AND(LEN(E274)<>0,LEN($F$274:$U$274)=0)`

I am stuck on what to put in the *Applies to* box. Currently it just selects one cell.

My main problem is replicating the formula over each given column in the row without creating tons of rules. Then if possible I want to do the same thing for about 200 rows.

Comment: Then you just want to highlight all the cells that aren't empty?!

Comment: Yes but only if a particular cell isn't empty. Anyway It's been solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to highlight something in A1:h18, and the specific cell ist always in column then (if i understand you right) 
1. mark a1:h18
2. and use the following formula

```
=AND(LEN($a1)<>0,LEN(a1)<>0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's basically what I needed - I changed just changed <> to =

I used: AND(LEN($F13)<>0,LEN(F13)=0)